# Typescript component: template works but templateurl does not

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm developing with Ionic 2 and am having a problem with Typescript component templates.

From a page, `DataPage` in the code below, I need to generate and present a modal view when a button is clicked. When I use `templateUrl` in the modal component, I am presented with an error, shown in the second code block.

I'm confident the file itself is being detected, as changing the path produces an transpilation error when Ionic is serving the app. Also, using `template` and simply copying in the contents from the referenced file works nicely - so I'm reasonably confident in the validity of the markup. I've also tried `template` and `templateUrl` with a much more simple markup, with the same results.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-data',
  templateUrl: 'data.html'
})
export class DataPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  testKnowledge() {
    console.log('Click');
    let knowledgeModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DataModal);
    console.log('Modal created');
    knowledgeModal.present();
    console.log('Modal presented');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dataModal',
  templateUrl: 'dataModal.html'
})
export class DataModal {
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  modalDismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
md@MBP:~/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq$ ionic serve --lab

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--lab"

keywords if/then/else require v5 option
[14:46:10]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47 
[14:46:10]  watch started ... 
[14:46:10]  build dev started ... 
[14:46:10]  clean started ... 
[14:46:10]  clean finished in 9 ms 
[14:46:10]  copy started ... 
[14:46:10]  transpile started ... 
[14:46:14]  transpile finished in 3.79 s 
[14:46:14]  webpack started ... 
[14:46:14]  copy finished in 3.99 s 
/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:95
      var code = nextLine.substr(0, mapping.generatedColumn -
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:95:30)
at Array.forEach (native)
at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap] (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:80:24)
at SourceMapSource.node (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/SourceMapSource.js:42:20)
at ReplaceSource.node (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ReplaceSource.js:66:29)
at CachedSource.node (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/CachedSource.js:12:23)
at /Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource.js:40:49
at Array.map (native)
at ConcatSource.node (/Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource.js:39:60)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--lab"
npm ERR! node v7.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--lab"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--lab"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--lab"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/md/Documents/Development/MobileDevelopment/aq/npm-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? I don't mind working with `template` in the short term, but that isn't going to fly when I'm ready to release.

Edit:

I'm working with an installation of Ionic as per their guidance notes, I didn't install Webpack directly, but the CLI feedback indicates this is running.

Comment: do you use webpack?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, I've updated the code to reflect the full logging from when I call Ionic to serve. I've also added in a note about Webpack. How could Webpack be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

If your're using webpack you can do like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-data',
  templateUrl: 'data.html'
})
export class DataPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  testKnowledge() {
    console.log('Click');
    let knowledgeModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DataModal);
    console.log('Modal created');
    knowledgeModal.present();
    console.log('Modal presented');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-dataModal',
  templateUrl: require('./dataModal.html') //<-- check the path of your html
})
export class DataModal {
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  modalDismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

I think the problem is your path .. if you use webpack try with require

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to change your `templateUrl` to this:

```
  templateUrl: './data.html'
```

and

```
  templateUrl: './dataModal.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it yet, but I had the same problem and solved it by writing the modal component decorator all in one line:

```
@Component({ selector: 'page-dataModal', templateUrl: 'dataModal.html' })
```

As said [here](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/issues/247), it seems to be an issue of *source-map*.